# Phpdoc No Summary found for this file

Tags: php, phpdoc

I've installed phpDoc on our server, set up etc. It's producing documentation correctly.
We're using the 'Responsive' template, however this error occurs regardless of the template used.

Under the 'Errors', each file scanned seems to have the following error:

```
Type        Line    Description
error       0       No summary was found for this file
```

I've googled exhaustively for this, and can't find a solution. I've even gone through the effort of tracking down the server error code behind the message `PPC:ERR-50000` and attempting to track back the condition which causes the error, but got a bit lost.

**My Question:**

What does this error mean? Why is it on line 0, and how the hell do I get rid of it?! Even if I have done the docblock correctly, can I hide this error? My error-free ocd is going crazy!

Many thanks

**EDIT**
Some extra information: Each of my files have the following docblock from line 1 of the file:

```
<?php 
    /**
     * Short Description
     *
     * Long Description
     *
     * @package      Some Package
     * @subpackage   Some Subpackage
     * @category     Some Category
     * @author       F Bloggs <gbloggs@email.com>
     */
?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

But does the top of your file have *two* such docblocks?  The first docblock is expected to be the one for the file itself, and a second docblock should pair up with the first documentable code element that appears after it.

However, if you only have one docblock at the top of the file, it will get paired up with the first code element found, thus the "file itself" will seem to be missing its docblock.  That is what that error is supposed to indicate.

Comment: That does make sense! I will test it later. Out of curiosity, if its a 1 class per file policy, is there much point to having a file summary and class summary - technically both would be the same thing? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: One Class Per File is a convention, sure, but not a restriction, so there are users out there that do things in one file in a way that makes a file-level docblock necessary from an organizing perspective.  But mostly, it's a holdover from the phpdoc 1.x world, where there were no namespaces and only a minority of coders followed a coding standard :-)

Comment: For me, i usually only create file-level docblock when there is a bunch of funtions in a file. Using it as a sort of class docblock for global functions.

Comment: What about when there are no code elements in the file? I'm getting this error on some files that have docblocks but no code. They have no code because no code has been created in them yet. They also have `@ignore` tags for this very reason. Simply ignoring the error is not an acceptable answer because the standard at our shop is that tests and documentation builds should run clean, without errors.

Comment: @JayBienvenu: if there are no code elements in the file, then I would expect phpDocumentor to either completely skip the file, or at least use the first docblock as the file-level docblock.  If you're seeing errors tied to a file that has no actual code elements in it, then I'd say there's a bug in phpDocumentor.  Granted, a PHP file with docblocks but zero code elements is an edge case, so it's very feasible that it's an unhandled scenario in the code.

Answer (score 5):

@ashnazg is right but I want to improve your answer with an example.

A *File-level DocBlock* should be the first docblock and must have a **Summary** (in this example the summary is "*Class Category | core/Category.class.php*").
Then a *Class-level DocBlock* is placed before a class definition.

```
<?php
/**
 * Class Category | core/Category.class.php
 *
 * @package     MyApp XYZ
 * @subpackage  Categories
 * @author      Sandro Miguel Marques <sandromiguel@something.com>
 * @version     v.1.1 (06/12/2016)
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2016, Sandro
 */

namespace Myapp;

use \PDO;
use \Exception;
use \PDOException;

/**
 * Class Category - active record
 *
 * Recipe categories
 */
class Category {

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

So after a lot of searching on the server, I have a semi-fix for the problem should anyone else be encountering the same issue.

I've found out how to hide the error from the documentation, but not what is causing it.

If the error you are receiving is on Line 0, and is no summary found for this file, then you will need to edit the following file:

```
phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Plugin/Core/Transformer/Writer/xml.php
```

You will then need to search for the protected method: `createErrorEntry()`

This is what the existing method looks like:

```
protected function createErrorEntry($error, $parse_errors)
{
    $marker_obj = new \DOMElement(strtolower($error->getSeverity()));
    $parse_errors->appendChild($marker_obj);

    $message = ($this->getTranslator())
        ? vsprintf($this->getTranslator()->translate($error->getCode()), $error->getContext())
        : $error->getCode();

    $marker_obj->appendChild(new \DOMText($message));
    $marker_obj->setAttribute('line', $error->getLine());
    $marker_obj->setAttribute('code', $error->getCode());
}
```

This method needs to have an `IF` condition added. Wrap the entire body of the method in the following IF condition:

```
protected function createErrorEntry($error, $parse_errors)
{
    if($error->getCode()!=='PPC:ERR-50000')
    {
        $marker_obj = new \DOMElement(strtolower($error->getSeverity()));
        $parse_errors->appendChild($marker_obj);

        $message = ($this->getTranslator())
            ? vsprintf($this->getTranslator()->translate($error->getCode()), $error->getContext())
            : $error->getCode();

        $marker_obj->appendChild(new \DOMText($message));
        $marker_obj->setAttribute('line', $error->getLine());
        $marker_obj->setAttribute('code', $error->getCode());
    }
}
```

This will stop the error being recorded, in effect, it hides the error from the end user, it doesn't fix what I can only assume is a bug in phpDocumentor. So the original error still exists, it just hasn't been recorded.

One thing I did note while debugging, is the `vsprintf()` function produces an error for on the PPC:ERR-50000 error. The `vsprintf()` produces the error `PHP Warning: vsprintf(): Too few arguments`. If i find out how to fix the code to stop the false error (or fix the comments to ensure the error isn't given reason to log), I'll post it here.

Comment: This question put me into the right direction. When using the 'clean' template however apparently the xml writer is not used. I found the problem could be fixed by changing the attached validators within the attachValidators method, located in **src\phpDocumentor\Descriptor\ServiceProvider.php**. Search for 'PPC:ERR-50000' and comment that line of code, this ensures files are not tested for this specific situation regardless of the used Transformer.

Comment: This just seems a bit excessive.  I'm not sure why you wouldn't just ignore the error?  phpDoc seems to be lagging a bit behind the times, I think that's a given.  Just do what feels right, and ignore 'errors' that you don't care about.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I've found that creating the documentation from the commandline using parameters rather than using parameters in  :

```
phpdoc -d ./ -t ./docs --ignore=vendor/*
```

vs parameters in a phpdoc.dist.xml configuration file has resolved all of the issues raised in this thread.

I don't think this stops the need for two docblocks at the top of files but it does appear to resolve the "No summary was found for this file" error when building the documentation.

Comment: agreed. I had this problem with view scripts for Zend Framework, files with the .phtml extension. I realized that this is not something that requires API documentation so I've instructed phpdoc to skip these files via a configuration directive and just trust myself to comment these files appropriately.

stated differently, if the file does not have more than one documentable code element, don't bother to generate phpdoc for it.

Comment: fwiw I was having the "no summary found" error occur when I used local paths starting with a dot. `./src` is bad, but `src` is okay. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error because I use PHP > 7 and PHPDocumentor did not recognize the syntax, so this "default error" was provided.

In my code, PHPDocumentor isn't able to parse null returns (?) in functions.

I solved this issue going to this link

https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/releases

I wgot the "PHP-7 Syntax support" and installed it

```
wget https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/releases/download/v2.9.0/phpDocumentor.phar
sudo mv phpDocumentor.phar /usr/local/bin/phpdoc
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpdoc
```

check version:

```
phpdoc --version
```

= phpDocumentor version v2.9.0

It works with this phpDocumentor version

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error message. I got rid of it..

the solution is very simple. in the file block at the
top, the summary line has a period at the end of it. This indicates
its a summary line.

make sure that no other blocks that follow for attributes or methods or whatever have a summary line with a period at the end. Once I removed those, the error disappeared immediately (PHPDocumentor 2.8.5)

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this issue when my site works with php v7.4 while phpDocumentor.phar is started with php v7.2.5 and there where strong typed properties in my class. Strong typed properties aren't allowed before php v7.4.0.

```
class Template
{
    /**
    * @var  string  The template with some replacement strings 
    */
    private string $template; 


  ....
```