# PHPDoc "No summary was found for this file" error

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

I am trying to generate PHPDocs for code I have written, but I am constantly getting an error telling me that "No summary was found for this file". I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312643/phpdoc-no-summary-found-for-this-file) page that had a similar topic, but it does not help this specific problem.

As far as I can tell, the example below is formatted properly, but it still will give me the error.

```
<?php
namespace App\Example;

/**
 * This is the summary section for the file itself.
 *
 * This Goes into more depth about the whole file.
 *`enter code here`
 * @author Some Author
 *
 */

/**
 * Some standard first function (function_1). This is a long description of the file just so that it
 * looks good in the example doc page. Don't worry about what all of this says, it is meaningless. This
 * is all part of the first paragraph, and is the main summary. the next part is the more detailed stuff
 * people can read if they want.
 *
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at falli maluisset nec, paulo deterruisset no vix. Prompta ancillae
 * cu mea, insolens recteque te pri, vulputate disputando persequeris id quo. Ei iracundia
 * efficiendi eos. Eam ut illum euismod erroribus, praesent assueverit at vix. Wisi nostrum ad vel,
 * pro an eros repudiare, ei mea fierent appareat deseruisse.
 *
 * @param ParameterType1 $param1 Param1 description.
 * @param string $param2 Param2 description.
 * @param string $param3 Param3 description.
 * @param $param4 - Param4 description.
 *
 * @return void
 */

function function_1(ParameterType1 $param1, $param2, $param3, &$param4)
{
    //This is the code.
}


/**
 * Some standard second function (function_2) This is a long description of the file just so that it
 * looks good in the example doc page. Don't worry about what all of this says, it is meaningless. This
 * is all part of the first paragraph, and is the main summary. the next part is the more detailed stuff
 * people can read if they want.
 *
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at falli maluisset nec, paulo deterruisset no vix. Prompta ancillae
 * cu mea, insolens recteque te pri, vulputate disputando persequeris id quo. Ei iracundia
 * efficiendi eos. Eam ut illum euismod erroribus, praesent assueverit at vix. Wisi nostrum ad vel,
 * pro an eros repudiare, ei mea fierent appareat deseruisse.
 *
 * @param ParamType2 $param1 Param1 description.
 * @param $param2 - Param2 description.
 *
 * @return string $returnStatement
 */

function function_2(ParamType2 $param1, &$param2) {
    //This is the code.
    return $returnStatement;
}

?>
```

I am sure it is a simple fix to the code to generate the DOCs properly, but it has been frustrating trying to figure out what is causing the error.

Comment: how did you invoke the php docs? and are you win or mac?

Comment: $ [PHPDOC_FOLDER]/bin/phpdoc -mac/linux, $ [PHPDOC_FOLDER]\bin\phpdoc.bat - windows

Comment: Try moving that first (summary) block above the namespace. That would fix the problem.