# phpDocumentor No summary was found for this file

Tags: php, phpdoc

I wrote docblock in my file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Delete Pub House
 *
 * To delete Pub House send request with DELETE method to server with json encoded data:(id, name)
 *
 * @package bookstore-api
 * @subpackage api
 */
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Method: PUT");
...
```

And the file is missing in documentation and I get the "No summary was found for this file" error. How to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phpdoc No Summary found for this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312643/phpdoc-no-summary-found-for-this-file)

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: Is there any other PHPDoc for a method?

Comment: No, there is only one phpdoc

Comment: Maybe that is the reason. Try creating a dummy method and add some PHPDoc over there.